inertia js Link component is not closing properly in Laravel Project
Link component from '@inertiajs/vue3' is not closing automatically. If closed manually its not getting proper indentation.
This is a laravel inertia vue project. Where i imported Link component from '@inertiajs/vue3'. It works fine but makes wrong code formatting.
extention used in vscode
auto-close-tag and vue - official
<script setup>
import { Link, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import Icon from '@/Shared/Icon.vue'
const page = usePage()
const isUrl = (...urls) => {
    let currentUrl = page.url.substr(1)
    if (urls[0] === '') {
        return currentUrl === ''
    }
    return urls.filter((url) => currentUrl.startsWith(url)).length
}

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <Link class="group flex items-center py-3" :href="route('dashboard')"
                :active="route().current('dashboard')">
            <icon name="dashboard" class="mr-2 w-4 h-4" />
            <div>Dashboard</div>
            </Link>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">

laravel inertia js vue Link problem
